# SharePoint 2016 Help with SP.FileCreationInformation and clientContext.get_web(); using JSOM

Tags: document-library, content-type, jsom, file-upload, document-set

I need to copy a document to a document set using JSOM. The below code create the file in my Document library succesfully. However I cannot figure out how to go a step further to change from document library to document set.

```
oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("mydocLibrary");  // LOCATION OF MY DOCMENT LIBRARY
```

This is my actual Doc Set location -- I need help here please!!

```
var documentSetFolder = "/sites/mytest/mydocLibrary/test01";  // LOCATION OF MY DOCUMENT SET
```

// calling fn to create a copy of the file as stored in Site Assets.
    createfile('http://mySPHost/sites/mytest/SiteAssets/myfile.txt');"

```
function createfile (url)   
{  
    var clientContext;  
    var oWebsite;  
    var oList;  
    var fileCreateInfo;  
    var fileContent;  

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();  

     var documentSetFolder = "/sites/mytest/mydocLibrary/test01";  // LOCATION OF MY DOCUMENT SET

    oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("mydocLibrary");  // LOCATION OF MY DOCMENT LIBRARY

    fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  


    fileCreateInfo.set_url("myfile.txt");  
    fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());  
    fileContent = url;  // current location of file to copy from

    for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++)   
    {  
        fileCreateInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));  
    }

// THIS NEEDS TO BE UPDATED TO POINT TO DOC SET LOCATION, BUT HOW?
    this.newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);  


    clientContext.load(this.newFile);  
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler), Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler));  



    function successHandler()   
    {  
       alert("FILE CREATED!");
    }  

    function errorHandler()   
    {  
       alert("File Creation Failed: " + arguments[1].get_message());  
    }  
}
```

I would appreciate your help please as stuck in this logic for long now :(

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this was simply achieved by updating the  SP.FileCreationInformation object set url to

```
fileCreateInfo.set_url("http://mySPServer/sites/mytest/mydocLibrary/MyDocSetName/myfile.txt");
```